# Все ли SQL-базы данных поддерживают синтаксис SQL-языка?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, синтаксис

Отличаются ли команды обращения к различным `SQL` (`MS SQL`, `MySQL`, `Oracle`)? Просто мне необходимо изучить работу в базе данных на основе `MS SQL` с помощью Java, а материала по этой теме очень мало...

Comment: Попробуйте использовать команды sql

Comment: Материала по этой теме невероятно много, без понятия, как вы ищите. SQL запросы действительно могут иметь разный синтаксис (зависит от СУБД), но зачастую он практически идентичен.

Comment: Базовые принципы одинаковы, но детали различаются

Comment: Само понятие `SQL-базы данных` как бы подразумевает поддержку синтаксиса SQL:)  
Хотя все более-менее поддерживают единый стандарт, но имеют свои особенности.  
Почти наверняка столкнётесь с тем, что у всех свои собственные способы определения автоинкрементных полей.
Можно ещё упомянуть, что язык хранимых процедур (и триггеров) у всех совершенно разные.

Answer (score 1):

В основном все `базы данных-SQL` поддерживают одинаковый синтаксис от `SQL`. По крайне мере самые базовые команды работают по одному синтаксису, что в `MySQL`, что в `MS SQL`. Возможен некоторый синтаксический сахар или наоборот, где-то придется указать название таблицы с указанием схемы. Поэтому мой тебе совет, пиши на всех `SQL-типовых` БД одинаковым синтаксисом и не беспокойся. Если что, разберешься сразу, так как отличия даже если есть, то они мелочные.